# Backup using rsnapshot not working

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot, rdiff-backup, rdiff

I have a server web based Linux and i want to make backup every hour using rsnapshot. this is my rsnapshot file configuration :

```
config_version  1.2
snapshot_root   /var/Majjane-Save/
cmd_cp      /bin/cp
cmd_rm      /bin/rm
cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger
cmd_du      /usr/bin/du
cmd_rsnapshot_diff  /usr/bin/rsnapshot-diff
retain      hourly  24
verbose     2
loglevel    3
logfile /var/log/rsnapshot.log
lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
exclude     /var/www/clients/
exclude     /var/www/apps/
backup  /var/www/   localhost/var/Majjane-Save/
```

The problem is when i make 3 backups for example :

- hourly.0 : the folder backuped has 15 files
- hourly.1 : the folder backuped has 14 files ( i removed one file from the folder /var/www/ )
- hourly.2 : the folder backuped has 15 files ( i created an other file different from the first one)

when i try to restore the first removed file from my backup hourly.0 i didn't find it, you can say that all of hourly.x folders are just a symbolic links no more.

Comment: the issue was that the folder who i backup-ed contains just symbolic links . thanx any way